# HTML/Angular2 date picker disable to select a future date

Tags: html, angular, datepicker

I have an issue related to html/angular 2 date picker.
So i have such input tag:

```
<input #createdAt ngModel type="datetime-local" id="createdAt" name="date" class="form-control" required>
```

but i don't want allow to a user select future date, so only today and past date is allowed.
How can i achieve such behaviour with angular 2?

Comment: First of all! Which datepicker are u using? Most of those datepicker fameworks contains implementations for date range selection

Comment: @Fals I'm using simple html input with type="datetime-local"

Comment: use mydatepicker it has these features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the option is to leverage the `max` attribute of `<input type="datetime-local` such as: `<input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">`

An alternative is to use an existing Angular2 component, such as the date picker from  [Bootstrap Angular 2](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker). The component is highly customizable and your goal can be achieved by setting the `maxDate` input.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the syntax for max/min attributes for the angular material date picker.

```
<input matInput [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="picker">
```

Comment: Yes, it seems now it's possible to use [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate". Thanks